# How do I reference a variable from another class in the same script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a wave spawn system in a serialized list in the inspector, but I can't figure out how to make it work. I can't seem to reference variables in other classes within the same script, and I need that data to make it work.

Right now it looks something like this, with classes nested within each other:

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class WaveSystemScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public WaveBubbleScriptableObject waveBubbleSO; //This contains the list of valid bubbles, but I can't reference it from the other classes.
    [SerializeField] public List<GameObject> validBubbles = new List<GameObject>(); //So does this
    [SerializeField] List<Waves> waveList = new List<Waves>();

}

[System.Serializable]
class Bubble
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject bubbleSelection; //select the bubble to spawn repeatedly
    [SerializeField] float spawnInterval;
}

[System.Serializable]
class Waves
{
    [SerializeField] List<Bubble> waveBubbles = new List<Bubble>(); //each wave may have multiple bubbles, with different variable each
    float waveLength;
}
```

`

The main issue is setting the bubbleSelection gameobject in the bubble class. Anything in the monobehaviour class can't be referenced in the other classes for a reason I'm not aware of. I tried lists, arrays and scriptableobjects but couldn't figure out how. I could reference the prefab directly using an empty GameObject variable, but I would like it to work such that all the valid spawnable objects are already present in an array/list or dropdown for easy selection.

Comment: Some reading on [C# Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) will likely help you out. If you're familiar with getters and setters in Java, they're essentially the same.

Comment: how are you trying to access properties?? Can you show that code

Comment: I am not using properties, though I appreciate the suggestion and will look into them :). The way I've been trying to access the data is by setting it in the inspector with either Lists or Arrays and trying to get a reference to that, either with ScriptableObjects or directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, both fields within `Bubbles` as well as within `Wave` have the [default member accessibility `private`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private) and therefore are not visible for any other type.

(See [access modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers))

---

You either simply want to make those `public` (in which case the [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) becomes redundant as it is only needed to serialize fields that are not `public`)

```
// [System.Serializable] <- this is also redundant as MonoBehaviour or anything 
// derived from UnityEngine.Object already is serialized anyway
public class WaveSystemScript : MonoBehaviour
{
     public WaveBubbleScriptableObject waveBubbleSO; 
     public List<GameObject> validBubbles = new List<GameObject>();
     public List<Waves> waveList = new List<Waves>();
}

[System.Serializable]
class Bubble
{
     public GameObject bubbleSelection;
     public float spawnInterval;
}

[System.Serializable]
class Waves
{
     public List<Bubble> waveBubbles = new List<Bubble>();
     public float waveLength;
}
```

or for encapsulation, depending on your use case, you can keep them as `private` so they are only editable via the Inspector but via code only provide them as `public` readonly [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) like e.g.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Waves
{
    [SerializeField] private List<Bubble> _waveBubbles = new List<Bubble>();
    [SerilaizeField] private float _waveLength;

    public IReadOnlyList<Bubble> waveBubbles => _waveBubbles;
    public float waveLength => _waveLength;
}
```